# Print all pairs in a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
PhonebookEntry pb1("olaNormann");
pb1.add("Home","11234567");
pb1.add("Work","11065432");
cout << pb1.getNumbers()["Home"] << endl;
cout << pb1.getNumbers()["Work"] << endl;

map<string,string>::iterator it;
for(it = pb1.getNumbers().begin(); it != pb1.getNumbers().end(); ++it){
    cout << (*it).first << ": " << (*it).second << endl;
}
```

I have used the first two cout's to ensure that the two pairs are added properly. The code will print out the first two numbers with labels Home and Work, but fails to print both numbers in the for loop. The for loop only prints out "Home: 11234567". Can anyone see why? Below is my header file with relevant method implemented.

```
class PhonebookEntry{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> numbers;
public:
    PhonebookEntry(std::string name) : name(name){}
    std::map<std::string, std::string> getNumbers() const {return numbers;}

    void add(const std::string label,const std::string number){numbers[label] = number;}
};
```

Comment: Does `getNumbers()` return a reference, or a copy of the map? If it returns a copy, then it's being destroyed before you iterate over it, so anything could happen.

Comment: What's the return value of `PhonebookEntry::getNumbers`? If it does not return a reference, you're creating a temporary, inserting a value, and printing it---without modifying the actual phonebook.

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin But isn't he inserting the values with the function `pb1.add()`?

Comment: this is my public get metdog: std::map<std::string, std::string> getNumbers() const {return numbers;}

Comment: @macs: Hopefully, it's hard to tell without more details :-).

Comment: @Skogen: please extend your example by providing the relevant code of `PhonebookEntry`, including `add`.

Comment: @Skogen: based on the code in your comment, you are doing what Matthias said.  You need to return it by reference.

Comment: please use `it->` instead of `(*it).` as the latter makes my eyes bleed...

Answer (score 6):

`getNumbers()` is returning a copy of the map, rather than a reference to it. That copy is destroyed at the end of the expression containing the function call, and so during the loop the iterator is invalid, and doing anything with it will give undefined behaviour.

It should look something like:

```
map<string,string> & getNumbers();
                   ^
```

where the `&` indicates a reference. It would also be polite to provide a `const` overload:

```
map<string,string> const & getNumbers() const;
                   ^^^^^^^              ^^^^^
```

With that change, your code should work as expected; [see demonstration](http://ideone.com/19i9k).

Comment: And even if the copy continued to exist the loop is comparing iterators from different copies, which isn't valid.

Comment: ../PhonebookEntry.cpp:14: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'it = ((const std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,

Comment: @Skogen: Perhaps you've only got the `const` version? That's fine if you don't want to expose a modifiable reference, but you'll need to change the type of `it` to `const_iterator` in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your method:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> getNumbers() const {return numbers;}
```

then it is returning a copy of the `numbers` map. So in your loop, the iterators are all messed up:

```
for(it = pb1.getNumbers().begin(); it != pb1.getNumbers().end(); ++it) { ... }
```

First, it gets initialized with one copy of the map. Then, it gets compared against the end iterator of *another copy*. You need to return the map by reference:

```
const std::map<std::string, std::string>& getNumbers() const {return numbers;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate issues going on here:

1. Inserting a value into a temporary and printing it
2. Using an iterator of a temporary after its destruction

### Issue 1

```
cout << pb1.getNumbers()["Home"] << endl;
```

You see output because `std::map<T,U>::operator[]` returns `U&`, which is still valid when `operator<<(std::cout, U&)` is called. However, the temporary is destroyed at the of the expression.

### Issue 2

```
for(it = pb1.getNumbers().begin(); it != pb1.getNumbers().end(); ++it) { ... }
```

The temporary returned by `getNumbers()` is invalid in the loop body, as Mike explains well in his answer.